# Yii2 - Form validation rules: How to use custom validation function or alternative?

Tags: php, validation, yii, yii2

I am using *Yii 2.0,* I can't figure out how to validate the value of the selected option in the drop-down list, I need to check, if its greater than ZERO.

What i have so far

in the Rules array

```
['year', 'required'],
['day', 'required'],
['month', 'checkDefaultValue'],...
```

The custom validate method is

```
public function checkDefaultValue() {
    if ($this->month > 0) {
        $this->addError('month', 'Month error message...');
    }
}
```

This code isn't working, is there a better way for doing it?

Comment: your array is like ["Jan", "Feb"]
OR [0=>JAN, 1=> "Feb"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
['month', 'in','range' => ['Jan','Feb']],
```

Specify the range in which the values should be.

Comment: Thanks, its working, but what if i need to create a condition like != or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because it adds the error if the month is greater than zero, which is the opposite of what you want.
This would work:

```
public function checkDefaultValue() {
    if ($this->month <= 0) {
        $this->addError('month', 'Month error message...');
    }
}
```

Or use the default number validator to do that and even more:

```
[
    ['month'], 
    'number', 
    'integerOnly' => true,
    'min' => 1,
    'tooSmall'=>'the selected item is too small for month!!!',
    'max' => 12,
    'tooBig'=>'the selected item is too big for month!!!',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `range` validator, if you still want to do a `custom validation` [this](http://www.devprofessor.com/yii2/use-yii2-custom-validation/) will help you.